# How to execute Linux Command through Python to Start and Stop of SAP Host Agent?

Tags: python-3.x

Could you please suggest on how to execute Linux command through Python to ***Start*** & ***Stop*** SAP Host Agent.

Path: `.(/usr/sap/hostctrl/exe)`

To stop hostagent: `./saphostexec -stop`
To start hostagent: `./saphostexec -start`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Bash commands in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python)

Answer (score -1):

we can use the os module of python to do it.

```
import os

os.chdir('/usr/sap/hostctrl/exe')

# for starting hostagent
os.system("./saphostexec -start pf=host_profile")

# to know the status of hostagent
os.system("./saphostexec -status pf=host_profile")

# for stopping hostagent
os.system("./saphostexec -start pf=host_profile")
```